# Not able to access documents in a collection Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array of objects which comes from firestore `all_categories`.

```
let docID = getStoreID();
    let all_categories = [];
    db
        .collection("STORES")
        .doc(docID)
        .collection("CATEGORIES")
        .orderBy("CAT_ADDED_ON","desc")
        .limit(5).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            all_categories.push(doc.data())
          })
    })
```

When I `console.log(all_categories)` It shows it has 2 objects but when I try to iterate through them it shows `undefiened`.

Like this:

```
all_categories.forEach(category => {
  console.log(category)
})
```

The console does not print anything.

What can be the problem?

Comment: where are you using console.log inside then or after then? it takes some time to get the data if you using outside of then it will not print anything.

Comment: how about this `    db
        .collection("STORES")
        .doc(docID)
        .collection("CATEGORIES")
        .orderBy("CAT_ADDED_ON","desc")
        .limit(5).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            all_categories.push(doc.data())
          })
    }).then(()=>{
all_categories.forEach(category => {
  console.log(category)
})
})`

Comment: Thanks This worked u can write this code in the answers and I will accept the answer.

Comment: sure thanks i will write it in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieving data from a database is a asynchronous process you can attach another `then` to it like this when the previous then is completed it will run the after one.

```
 db.collection("STORES")
 .doc(docID)
 .collection("CATEGORIES")
 .orderBy("CAT_ADDED_ON","desc")
 .limit(5)
 .get()
 .then((querySnapshot) => { querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => { all_categories.push(doc.data())})
 .then(()=>{ all_categories.forEach(category => { console.log(category) })
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

`get()` is asynchronous (returns a `Promise`) meaning that it will move on to another task before it finishes. The `then()` method returns a `Promise`. It takes up to two arguments: callback functions for the success and failure cases of the Promise. Therefore you have to do the following to be able to access the `category` elements:

```
let docID = getStoreID();
    let all_categories = [];
    db
        .collection("STORES")
        .doc(docID)
        .collection("CATEGORIES")
        .orderBy("CAT_ADDED_ON","desc")
        .limit(5).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            all_categories.push(doc.data());
             all_categories.forEach(category => {
                console.log(category)
            })
          })
    })
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then